# Flutter Googleapis_auth get new access token from refresh Token

Tags: flutter, google-oauth

I'm using `Googleapis_auth` to access some `Google API`, i store credentials in local storage so i can access that api later, but it expires in one hour as a read.

I want to get a new access token after the first one is expired using the saved credential `refreshToken`, but i don't know how to do that.

This is the code i use to get the user credentials:

```
var authClient = await clientViaUserConsent(
    ClientId(_clientId, _clientSecret), 
    _scopes,
    (url) { launch(url);}
);
//Save Credentials
await storage.saveCredentials(authClient.credentials.accessToken,
    authClient.credentials.refreshToken);
return authClient;
```

And this is how i use the saved credentials:

```
return authenticatedClient(
        http.Client(),
        AccessCredentials(
            AccessToken(credentials["type"], credentials["data"],
                DateTime.tryParse(credentials["expiry"])),
            credentials["refreshToken"],
            _scopes)
);
```

But as i said above when the credentials expires i have no idea how i make use of the `refreshToken` to get a new access token.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

```
AccessCredentials newCredentials = await refreshCredentials(
          ClientId(_clientId, _clientSecret),
            AccessCredentials(
                AccessToken(credentials["type"], credentials["data"],
                DateTime.tryParse(credentials["expiry"])),
                credentials["refreshToken"],
                _scopes
            ),
            http.Client()
    );


    return authenticatedClient(
          http.Client(),
          newCredentials
    );
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, care to elaborate a little bit, where do you get then `credentials["type"]` `credentials["data"]` `credentials["expiry"]` and `credentials["refreshToken"]` ? thanks in advance!